# implement network security in c#.net(oracle odp.net)

Tags: c#

In my windows application I am getting data from oracle by calling stored procedure and populating it in grid (VS 2010).

Can anyone help in implementing network security? Whether we need to implement it in c# level or database level and how can we do it. How can we use odp.net to implement the security. Data should be encrypted in network while getting data from database.

Comment: Whats your objective? What you want to achieve?

Comment: When we get data(select query) from database into front end data is not secured and outsiders can view the data a it s plain.Others should not be able to hack data by accessing network.Is there any way?